# JavaScript function intermittently calling onclick A link

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to send events in Google Analytics.  If I click the link the event does not post.  If I click the link several times in rapid succession, a few of the clicks will register.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the function not having a chance to run before the page reloads.  In practice the link will take the user to a different page but right now it just points to itself.

How can I make a change to the code to ensure the function will be called properly while preserving the function of the A link?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include "user/ga.htm";?><!--ga code-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
                var a = document.getElementById("alert");
                a.onclick = function() { 
                ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'login');//intermittent
                //alert('yo!');//always works.
             }
        }
    //ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'login');//always works
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a id = "alert" href = "test.php"> test </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. You seem to want it to tell google someone logged in. Instead of calling this function when clicking on it, you might want to consider calling the function on pageload of your next webpage, that way you don't have to worry about executiontime

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Some of the events I can do this, such as login or register.  Other events such as clicking on a paypal link or download button seem to require this set up.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to change very little functionality, but ensure the code is properly called, by targeting a new tab.

```
<a id = "alert" href = "test.php" target = "_blank"> test </a>
```

This works perfectly for download links.  Things like logging in could be addressed in the way Nicky Smits suggested in his answer.  But other things like linking to an external website (like paypal) in the same tab, won't work.

Comment: I feel like this a suboptimal solution so I am not going to accept it in case someone has a proper solution.